# Handling 'Task Was Canceled' Error in ASP.NET Core 6.5 AppService Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a `RoomChange` method in my ASP.NET Core application (version 6.5) that contains several asynchronous service calls to update the database. Among these calls, one operates within a loop. However, I'm encountering frequent 'A task was canceled' errors, particularly within the loop's async-await update method. I suspect this might be due to a timeout issue, but I'd like to explore potential solutions without altering the timeout settings.

Here's an overview of the code:

```
public async Task RoomChange(RoomChangeDto input)
{
    try
    {
        var reservation = await _reservationManager.GetAsync(input.Id);
        var oldRoomNo = await _roomNoAppService.GetDetail(new EntityDto((int)reservation.RoomNoId));
        var updateOldRoomNoStatus = new UpdateRoomStatusDto
        {
            Id = oldRoomNo.Id,
            RoomStatusId = (int)DefaultRoomStatus.Available,
        };

        if (reservation.ReservationStatusId == (int)DefaultReservationStatus.CheckIn)
        {
            updateOldRoomNoStatus.RoomStatusId = (int)DefaultRoomStatus.CheckOut;
        }

        await _roomNoAppService.UpdateRoomNoStatus(updateOldRoomNoStatus);

        var newRoomNo = await _roomNoAppService.GetDetail(new EntityDto<int>(input.RoomNoId));

        if (input.EffectiveDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
        {
            var updateNewRoomNoStatus = new UpdateRoomStatusDto
            {
                Id = newRoomNo.Id,
                RoomStatusId = oldRoomNo.RoomStatusId,
            };
            await _roomNoAppService.UpdateRoomNoStatus(updateNewRoomNoStatus);
        }

        var reservationRooms = (await _reservationRoomAppService.GetListForRoomChange(input.Id, input.EffectiveDate, reservation.CheckOutDate)).Items.ToList();
        foreach (var item in reservationRooms)
        {
            item.RoomNoId = input.RoomNoId;
            await _reservationRoomAppService.UpdateAsync(item);
        }

        ObjectMapper.Map(input, reservation);
        await _reservationManager.UpdateAsync(reservation);
        
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return $"Error during RoomChange: {ex.Message}";
    }
}
```

The method involves multiple asynchronous database updates and an async loop to update reservation room details. Despite implementing try-catch blocks, I'm consistently encountering 'Task Was Canceled' errors, particularly within the loop's async-await update method.

I'm seeking advice on potential solutions or best practices to address this 'Task Was Canceled' error within the loop, considering alternative strategies without modifying the timeout settings. Any suggestions or insights to manage these async operations more effectively in ASP.NET Core 6.5 would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi，@phonemyat ，could you show the detailed message?

Comment: CancellationToken = IsCancellationRequested = false
Data = {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult = -2146233029
Message = "A task was canceled."
Source = "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational"
StackTrace = "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand. 
  <ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()\r\n   at 
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand. 
  <ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
TargetSite = {Void MoveNext()}
Task = Id = 6180, Status = Canceled, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"  (here error detail thanks)